# REACT Context Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have trouble with react context.
Especially with function getProductCategory which I use in the second component.
My React context provider looks like :

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from "./data";

export const ProductContext = createContext();

const ProductContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [productsCategory, setProductCategory] = useState();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(data);
  });
  function getProductCategory(category) {
    const productFromCategory = data.filter(
      (product) => product.type === category
    );
    setProductCategory(productFromCategory); //this line is causing the problem
    console.log(productFromCategory);
    return productsCategory;
  }
  const getProduct = (product) => {
    const currentProduct = products
      ? products.filter((item) => item.slug === product)[0]
      : undefined;

    return currentProduct;
  };
 
  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{ getProduct, getProductCategory }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProductContextProvider;
```

I want to get access to my context from another component Mats which is a page.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { ProductContext } from "../../context";
/accesoriesComponent/CategoryTitle/CategoryTitle";
import Filters from "../../components/accesoriesComponent/Filters/Filters";
import ProductWrapper from "../../components/accesoriesComponent/ProductWrapper/ProductWrapper";
export default function Mats(props) {
  const { getProductCategory } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const mats = getProductCategory("mats");
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Filters />
        {mats && <ProductWrapper products={mats} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I want to visit page Mats, I get error "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside component WillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.".
I marked the line of code in the first code, that courses the problem .
I don't know how to handle it.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi, add empty array as dependency in  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(data);
  }, []);

Comment: It does not work also

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:-

- instead of `return`-ing `productsCategory` from your `getProductCategory` function. Send your `productsCategory` as `ProductContext.Provider` `values` `props`
- Btw, your `useEffect` should have `[]` or `empty` `array` as **dependency**
- `ProductContextProvider.js`:-

```js
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from "./data";

export const ProductContext = createContext();

const ProductContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [productsCategory, setProductCategory] = useState();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(data);
  }, []); // making sure it will only run once when rendered

  function getProductCategory(category) {
    const productFromCategory = data.filter(
      (product) => product.type === category
    );
    setProductCategory(productFromCategory); // you already set the data in here
    console.log(productFromCategory);
    // return productsCategory; // no need to return this
  }
  const getProduct = (product) => {
    const currentProduct = products
      ? products.filter((item) => item.slug === product)[0]
      : undefined;

    return currentProduct;
  };
 
  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{ productsCategory, getProduct, getProductCategory }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProductContextProvider;
```

- So in `Mats.js`, just get display your updated ``

```js
export default function Mats(props) {
  const { productsCategory, getProductCategory } = useContext(ProductContext);
  
  // Shouldn't do this. Cause it will keep rerender
  // const mats = getProductCategory("mats");

  // default state of category
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('mats')

  // use useffect to send the updated products by category
  useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      if(category) {
        getProductCategory(category);
      }
    })()
  }, [category]) // will initiated every time category change
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Filters />
        {productsCategory && <ProductWrapper products={productsCategory} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```